# Can getopts parse a subset of a bash script's arguments and leave the rest intact?

Tags: bash, getopts

I am using `getopts` to parse arguments in a `bash` script. I want to do two things:

- remove processed options from `"$@"`
- leave unprocessed options in `"$@"`

consider the command-line

```
$ foo -a val_a -b val_b -c -d -e -f val_f positional_l positional_2 ...
```

Where `foo` uses `getopts` to parse options defined by a *optstring* of `'b:c'` and afterwards needs to leave `"$@"` as

```
`-a val_a -d -e -f val_f positional_l positional_2 ...`
```

I need to do two things:

- parse a subset of options that may be given
- leave all other opptions intact

The reason for this is because `foo` must use the options it recognises to determine another script `bar` to which it must pass the remaining `"@"`.

Normally `getopts` stops when it encounters an unrecognised option but I need it to continue (up to any `--`). I need it to proceess and remove the options it recognises and leave alone those that it doesn't.

---

I did try to work around my problem using `--` between the `foo` options and the `bar` options but `getopts` seems to baulk if the text following `--` begins with a `-` (I tried but could not escape the hyphen).

Anyway I would prefer not to have to use `--` because I want the existence of `bar` to be effectively transparent to the caller of `foo`, and I'd like the caller of `foo` to be able to present the options in any order.

I also tried listing all `bar`options in `foo` (i.e. using `'a:b:cdef:'`for the *optstring*) without processing them but I need to delete the processed ones from `"$@"` as they occur. I could not work out how to do that (`shift` doesn't allow a position to be specified).

---

I can manually reconstruct a new options list (see my own answer) but I wondered if there was a better way to do it.

Comment: One (seemingly insurmountable) problem: if you see `-a -b 3`, is that an unknown option `-a` with no argument followed by the expected `-b` option, or is it an unknown option `-a` with an argument `-b` followed by a positional argument `3`?

Comment: @chepner: Good point. The other problem: is `-ab` option `-a` with option-argument `b`, or an option group to be interpreted as `-a` and `-b`?

Comment: That looks even more insurmountabler :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following, which **only requires the script's *own* options to be known in advance**:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

passThru=() # init. pass-through array
while getopts ':cb:' opt; do # look only for *own* options
  case "$opt" in
    b)
      file="$OPTARG";;
    c) ;;
    *) # pass-thru option, possibly followed by an argument
      passThru+=( "-$OPTARG" ) # add to pass-through array
      # see if the next arg is an option, and, if not,
      # add it to the pass-through array and skip it
      if [[ ${@: OPTIND:1} != -* ]]; then
        passThru+=( "${@: OPTIND:1}" )
        (( ++OPTIND ))
      fi
      ;;
  esac
done
shift $((OPTIND - 1))
passThru+=( "$@" )  # append remaining args. (operands), if any

./"$file" "${passThru[@]}"
```

*Caveats*: There are two types of **ambiguities that cannot be resolved this way**:

- For pass-thru options *with option-arguments*, this approach only works if the argument isn't *directly* appended to the option.
  E.g., `-a val_a` works, but `-aval_a` wouldn't (in the absence of `a:` in the `getopts` argument, this would be interpreted as an option *group* and turn it into multiple options `-a`, `-v`, `-a`, `-l`, `-_`, `-a`).
- As [chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126841/chepner) points out in a comment on the question, `-a -b` could be option `-a` with option-argument `-b` (that just happens to look like an option itself), or it could be distinct options `-a` and `-b`; the above approach will do the latter.

To resolve these ambiguities, you must stick [with your own approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40088479/45375), which has the down-side of requiring knowledge of all possible pass-thru options in advance.

Comment: Similar to what I had except for the wildcard case. I think those caveats are quite obscure and reasonably ignorable to gain the benefit of not requiring prior knowledge of pass-thru arguments. I didn't appreciate that you could alter the getopts variables. Nice solution.

Answer (score 3):

You can manually rebuild the options list like this example which processes the `-b` and `-c` options and passes anything left intact.

```
#!/bin/bash
while getopts ":a:b:cdef:" opt
do
  case "${opt}" in
    b) file="$OPTARG" ;;
    c) ;;
    *) opts+=("-${opt}"); [[ -n "$OPTARG" ]] && opts+=("$OPTARG") ;;
  esac
done
shift "$((OPTIND-1))"
./$file "${opts[@]}" "$@"
```

So

```
./foo -a 'foo bar' -b bar -c -d -e -f baz one two 'three and four' five
```

would invoke `bar`, given as the argument to option `b`, as

```
./bar -a 'foo bar' -d -e -f baz one two 'three and four' five
```

This solution suffers the disadvantage that the *optstring* must include the pass-through options (i.e. `":a:b:cdef:"` instead of the preferable `":b:c"`).

---

Replacing the argument list with the reconstructed one can be done like this:

```
set -- "${opts[@]}" "$@"
```

which would leave `"$@"` containing the unprocessed arguments as specified in the question.